# Paint.NET freezes on new tab, but isn't consuming many resources

Tags: freeze, tabs, paint.net

I have Paint.NET open with many tabs of reference material so I can create some new art. None are extraordinarily large images, but there are a couple dozen tabs.

It freezes whenever I open a new tab. However, it's only using ~500MB of RAM (32GB total in the machine, only ~50% of which is being used when I see this behavior), the CPU isn't being hit hard, and the images are on an SSD. So it's not a lack of resources that's causing this freeze.

What's going on? As long as I've used it, it's always done this. Is there a way I can work around this? I'm using all the images I have open actively (they're references, so I'm tabbing between them frequently), so I can't just close some. I also can't seem to launch multiple instances of Paint.NET in case that might've helped.

---

This is Paint.NET version 4.1.6 running on Windows 10 (version 1803).

Comment: " it's only using ~500MB out of an available 16BG" - Can you explain what you mean?  If it's only 500 MB out of 16 GB (I assume that's what you mean), why do you say it's out of 16 GB instead of 32 GB, this statement is unclear and you should clarify it.  You don't indicate your OS, the version of Paint.NET you are using, or even if this is new or old behavior.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. Yes, I meant GB not BG. I say "out of an available 16GB" because the other 16GB (or so) is being taken up by other processes, and is thus unavailable. That's also why I noted the total. The OS is the latest stable version of Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question based on your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: “The OS is the latest stable version of Windows 10 Pro.“ - Windows 10 version 1803 isn’t the latest stable version.  That would either be 1809 or 1903.  Will any image of opened multiple times (how many tabs exactly) reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound will that help you track down this issue? Let's say yes, any image and any amount of tabs. How would the solution to that be different than specific images and 12 tabs exactly?

Comment: I wanted to try and reproduce the issue.  So can you edit your question and provide some specific information necessary to reproduce the problem?  If you can provide that information, that’s fine, just tell me now so I can do errands.

Comment: Newer versions of Windows 10 (1809 and newer) [have been unstable](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20october%202018%20update%20deleted%20files) Additionally, [as per Microsoft's advice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history), "We encourage you to wait until the feature update is offered to your device automatically", and this machine has not had that yet